# How to write a SQL query in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor

I want to write SQL query in EF Core. I use `AddDbContextFactory` service. Unfortunately, it does not have `SqlQuery` method. How can I write my queries?

My Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<DBContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings")),
    lifetime: ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

I inject DbContextFactory in my razor page:

```
@inject IDbContextFactory<DBContext> DbFactory
```

Here is my code:

```
string UserId = "a5bddfc0-ee0d-4d33-b384-60629154aad9";

using DBContext db = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<List<Post>>(@$"SELECT * FROM Posts AS P WHERE P.SenderId IN (SELECT FollowingId FROM Followers WHERE FollowerId = '{UserId}'); ");
```

Here is the error:

> 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'SqlQuery' and no accessible extension method 'SqlQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseFacade' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there any method for writing SQL queries?

**Question Update:**

I encounter the error even when I use `AddDbContext`. I use EF Core 6.

Comment: You might be missing a `using` at the top of your code file ... using entity framework core, whatever the exact library is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SqlQuery` is a method for entity framework (EF), and it does not belong to EF Core.

Add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` at the top of the code file.

and here is the code:

```
string UserId = "a5bddfc0-ee0d-4d33-b384-60629154aad9";

using DBContext db = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();
var result = db.Posts.FromSqlRaw(@$"SELECT * FROM Posts AS P WHERE P.SenderId IN (SELECT FollowingId FROM Followers WHERE FollowerId = '{UserId}'); ").ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah, but if you're going to do this, you might as well just use Dapper.